# Take user directly to the page where event date matches the current date (pagination)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, pagination

So i have the below function to get my posts, but i want user to go directly on a page where posts have date "today" thats not a event publish date but an date for when event is happening , like if i have events that have `man_date` field `2015-4-12` and today is `2015-4-12` i will see directly the page where that event is without taking those events on first page.

```
function get_table(){
                global $wpdb;
                $c_cid = $_REQUEST['cat'];
                if(isset($_REQUEST["page"])){
                    $page_number = filter_var($_REQUEST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH); //filter number
                    if(!is_numeric($page_number)){die('Invalid page number!');} //incase of invalid page number
                }else{
                    $page_number = 1; //if there's no page number, set it to 1
                }
                $item_per_page = 20;
                //get total number of records from database for pagination
                $get_total_row = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'tipo_manifestazione' AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = $c_cid AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' AND (wp_posts.vip = 'NULL' OR wp_posts.vip IS NULL) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'manifestazione' GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.ID DESC");
                $get_total_rows = count($get_total_row);
                //break records into pages
                $total_pages = ceil($get_total_rows/$item_per_page);

                //get starting position to fetch the records
                $page_position = (($page_number-1) * $item_per_page);

                ?>
            <section class="table_container">
                                            <div class="controls_container">
                                              <div class="control">
                                                <select id="months" name="months">
                                                  <option value="" selected>Seleziona Mese</option>
                                                  <option value="01">Gennaio</option>
                                                  <option value="02">Febbraio</option>
                                                  <option value="03">Marzo</option>
                                                  <option value="04">Aprile</option>
                                                  <option value="05">Maggio</option>
                                                  <option value="06">Giugno</option>
                                                  <option value="07">Luglio</option>
                                                  <option value="08">Agosto</option>
                                                  <option value="09">Settembre</option>
                                                  <option value="10">Ottobre</option>
                                                  <option value="11">Novembre</option>
                                                  <option value="12">Dicembre</option>
                                                </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="control">
                                                  <input type="text" name="location_search" id="location_search" placeholder="Luogo..."/>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="control">
                                                  <div class="loading" style="display:none;"></div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="control right">
                                                <?php echo paginate_function($item_per_page, $page_number, $get_total_rows, $total_pages); ?>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <header class="table_header">
                                              <div class="sec_th first">
                                                <span class="sec_th_t">Voto</span>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="sec_th second">
                                                <span class="sec_th_t">Data</span>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="sec_th third">
                                                <span class="sec_th_t">Manifestazione</span>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="sec_th fourth">
                                                <span class="sec_th_t">Località</span>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="sec_th fifth">
                                                <span class="sec_th_t">Percorso Lungo</span>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="sec_th sixth">
                                                <span class="sec_th_t">Info</span>
                                              </div>
                                              </header>
                                              <div id="rows_container">
                                              <?php
                                                   $query = "SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'tipo_manifestazione' AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = $c_cid AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' AND (wp_posts.vip = 'NULL' OR wp_posts.vip IS NULL) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'manifestazione' GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.ID DESC LIMIT $page_position, $item_per_page";

                                                      $posts = $wpdb->get_results($query);
                                                      foreach($posts as $post){
                                                        $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
                                                        $locations = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_locations WHERE post_id = $post->ID");
                                                        $l = $locations[0];
                                                  ?>
                                              <article id="row_<?php echo $post->ID;?>" class="table_row">
                                                <div class="ar_td first">
                                                  <span class="ar_td_t"><?php echo do_shortcode('[ratings id="'.$post->ID.'"]');?></span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="ar_td second">
                                                  <span class="ar_td_t"><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime(get_field('m_f_data',$post->ID)));?></span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="ar_td third">
                                                  <a href="<?php echo $permalink;?>"><span class="ar_td_t"><?php echo $post->post_title;?></span></a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="ar_td fourth">
                                                 <a href="<?php echo site_url();?>/geo/?location=<?php echo $l->luogo;?>"> <span class="ar_td_t"><?php echo $l->luogo;?></span></a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="ar_td fifth">
                                                  <span class="ar_td_t"><?php echo get_field('m_f_percorso_lungo',$post->ID);?></span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="ar_td sixth">
                                                  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="show_info('div_<?php echo $post->ID;?>','row_<?php echo $post->ID;?>');" class="show_button">Info +</a>
                                                </div>
                                              </article>
                                              <div id="div_<?php echo $post->ID;?>" class="div_content">
                                                <?php get_post_fields($post->ID);?>
                                              </div>
                                                  <?php
                                                  }
                                                ?>
                                              </div>
                                          </section>
                <?php
                exit();
            }

function paginate_function($item_per_page, $current_page, $total_records, $total_pages)
    {
        $pagination = '';
        if($total_pages > 0 && $total_pages != 1 && $current_page <= $total_pages){ //verify total pages and current page number
            $pagination .= '<ul class="pagination">';

            $right_links    = $current_page + 3; 
            $previous       = $current_page - 3; //previous link 
            $next           = $current_page + 1; //next link
            $first_link     = true; //boolean var to decide our first link

            if($current_page > 1){
                $previous_link = ($previous==0)?1:$previous;
                $pagination .= '<li class="first"><a href="#" data-page="1" title="First">&laquo;</a></li>'; //first link
                $pagination .= '<li><a href="#" data-page="'.$previous_link.'" title="Previous">&lt;</a></li>'; //previous link
                    for($i = ($current_page-2); $i < $current_page; $i++){ //Create left-hand side links
                        if($i > 0){
                            $pagination .= '<li><a href="#" data-page="'.$i.'" title="Page'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                        }
                    }   
                $first_link = false; //set first link to false
            }

            if($first_link){ //if current active page is first link
                $pagination .= '<li class="first active">'.$current_page.'</li>';
            }elseif($current_page == $total_pages){ //if it's the last active link
                $pagination .= '<li class="last active">'.$current_page.'</li>';
            }else{ //regular current link
                $pagination .= '<li class="active">'.$current_page.'</li>';
            }

            for($i = $current_page+1; $i < $right_links ; $i++){ //create right-hand side links
                if($i<=$total_pages){
                    $pagination .= '<li><a href="#" data-page="'.$i.'" title="Page '.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                }
            }
            if($current_page < $total_pages){ 
                    $next_link = ($i > $total_pages)? $total_pages : $i;
                    $pagination .= '<li><a href="#" data-page="'.$next_link.'" title="Next">&gt;</a></li>'; //next link
                    $pagination .= '<li class="last"><a href="#" data-page="'.$total_pages.'" title="Last">&raquo;</a></li>'; //last link
            }

            $pagination .= '</ul>'; 
        }
        return $pagination; //return pagination links
    }
```

ajax:

```
jQuery("#get_table").load(ajaxurl,{'action':'get_table','cat':cat,'page':page});
```

The code is working good , to get posts and also pagination working good , the only thing i'm unable to figure out , that how i can make this thing happen to take use directly on page where posts with current matching date are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check on the index of the item you want to display. You can do that using the same query you are using to count the total rows but excluding everything that is later then the selected date. Then you can find out the page you are suppose to be on by dividing the rows found by the page size.

Simple version would be (simplified code):

```
$page_size = 10;
$total_rows = count($db->query("SELECT * FROM events;"));
$past_present_rows = count($db->query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE date <= '2015-05-24';"));
$desired_page = ceil($past_present_rows / $page_size); // Use floor() if the first page is 0, ceil() is first page is 1.
```

So if we apply it to the code supplied:

```
function get_table(){
    global $wpdb;
    $c_cid = $_REQUEST['cat'];
    $item_per_page = 20;
    if(isset($_REQUEST["page"])){
        $page_number = filter_var($_REQUEST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH); //filter number
        if(!is_numeric($page_number)){die('Invalid page number!');} //incase of invalid page number
        }else{
            $get_past_row = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'tipo_manifestazione' AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = $c_cid AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' AND (wp_posts.vip = 'NULL' OR wp_posts.vip IS NULL) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'manifestazione' AND wp_post.man_date <= '2015-05-24' GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.ID DESC");
            $get_past_rows = count($get_past_row);
            $page_number = ceil($get_past_rows / $item_per_page);
        }
        //get total number of records from database for pagination
        $get_total_row = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'tipo_manifestazione' AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = $c_cid AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' AND (wp_posts.vip = 'NULL' OR wp_posts.vip IS NULL) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'manifestazione' GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.ID DESC");
        ...
```

Answer (score 5):

I figured this out by my self.

By using the below query i get the posts with current date and the dates that are passed.

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$posts_c = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE wp_posts.man_date <= $date");
```

with above code i will get the rows and now let's convert them to a count

```
$get_count = count($posts_c);
```

Now what i did was divide the number of posts by number of posts per page which is  `20`

```
 $page_on = ceil($get_count / 20);
```

Thats it $page_on object contains the value of page where we will send our user.

Comment: Isn't this the answer I posted two days earlier?

Comment: Yes, sorry for that , don't know why i did posted that, btw changed the accepted answer and awarded you a bounty . :).